# How can I loop through this array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given this script:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
var sentences= 
[
 ['journey27.mp4', 
  [
    [1, 2],
    [5, 7]
  ]
 ],
 ['journey28.mp4', 
  [
    [10, 12],
    [13, 17],
    [25, 36]
  ]
 ],
 ['journey30.mp4', 
  [
    [13, 15],
    [15, 19],
    [21, 30]
  ]
 ]
];

function playVideo(myUrl, startTime, endTime) { 
  var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  video.src = myUrl;
  video.currentTime=startTime;
  video.play();

  var maxTime = endTime;
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(video.currentTime >= maxTime){
     playVideo(myUrl, startTime, endTime);
    }
  }, false);
} 

function myLoop(){
  I want to loop each pairs 5 times before jump to the next pair
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="myVideo" width="1000" height="800" controls autoplay loop>

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<br>
<a  onclick="myLoop()" > Play </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to fill in `myLoop` function.

I want to loop each pairs 5 times before jump to the next pair in the array.

For example,
-the first pair: 'journey27.mp4', **loop** "`[1, 2]`" 5 times

then the next pair: 'journey27.mp4', **loop** "`[5, 7]`" 5 times

then the next pair: 'journey28.mp4', **loop** "`[10, 12]`" 5 times

then the next pair: 'journey28.mp4', **loop** "`[13, 17]`" 5 times

and so on

**Note:** The `playVideo` function above works

**How can I loop through this array using javascript?**

Comment: MDN has [a pretty good page about loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration). What have you tried so far, and how have your attempts failed?

Comment: @Tom I don't think he actually wants a loop. I think each click on the button is supposed to play one video, but it's supposed to play the same video 5 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use global variables to hold the current indexes and repetition count for the video. Increment the repetition count, and when reaches `5` increment the indexes.

There's no loop, the iteration happens when the user clicks the link.

```js
var sentences= 
[
 ['journey27.mp4', 
  [
    [1, 2],
    [5, 7]
  ]
 ],
 ['journey28.mp4', 
  [
    [10, 12],
    [13, 17],
    [25, 36]
  ]
 ],
 ['journey30.mp4', 
  [
    [13, 15],
    [15, 19],
    [21, 30]
  ]
 ]
];

function playVideo(myUrl, startTime, endTime) { 
  console.log(`Playing ${myUrl} from ${startTime} to ${endTime}`);
} 

let video_index = 0;
let time_index = 0;
let repeat = 0;

function myLoop(){
  playVideo(sentences[video_index][0], sentences[video_index][1][time_index][0], sentences[video_index][1][time_index][1]);
  repeat++;
  if (repeat >= 5) {
    repeat = 0;
    time_index++;
    if (time_index >= sentences[video_index][1].length) {
      time_index = 0;
      video_index++;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myLoop()" > Play </a>
```

Comment: I think this overlooks the fact that each iteration needs to wait X seconds for the video to play. So, `playVideo` might need to return a Promise that resolves when the player reaches `endTime`, and `myLoop` would `await` each invocation before proceeding to the next.

Comment: Nothing is calling `playVideo` in a loop, it's only called when the user clicks the link.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. I do think that's a problem, because OP does explicitly state that they want the same segment to play 5 times in succession. It is possible that OP's question is ambiguous in this regard, and that they want the first 5 _button presses_ to play the same segment, and then the next 5 button presses to play a different segment, etc. (Like how clicking on units repeatedly in Warcraft caused them to grow irate.) We'll see what OP has to say.

Comment: You're right, I didn't see "autoplay loop" in the code. I thought he wanted to start each video when clicked.

Comment: I am sorry, it should play "Playing journey27.mp4 from 1 to 2" 5 times, then it plays "Playing 'journey27.mp4' from 5 to 7" 5 times, then it plays "Playing 'journey28.mp4' from 10 to 12" 5 times and so on. However, your code just play "Playing journey27.mp4 from 1 to 2" forever. Can you update your code?

Comment: Click more than 5 times and you'll see it change.

Comment: Yes, but I want it to run automatically. Maybe, my question is not clear enough. You can see my new question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73368419/can-we-create-a-loop-inside-the-video-addeventlistener-to-complete-this-task-ja) to know exactly what I want

Comment: As I said above, I misunderstood the question.