# Can we create a loop inside the video.addEventListener to complete this task (javascript)?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
var sentences= 
[
 ['journey27.mp4', 
  [
    [1, 2],
    [5, 7]
  ]
 ],
 ['journey28.mp4', 
  [
    [10, 12],
    [13, 17],
    [25, 36]
  ]
 ],
 ['journey29.mp4', 
  [
    [13, 15],
    [15, 19],
    [21, 30]
  ]
 ]
];

const firstVideo=sentences[0];
const firstTimes=firstVideo[1];
var firstUrl='video/'+firstVideo[0];
var firstStartTime=firstTimes[0][0,0];
var firstEndTime=firstTimes[0][0,1];

function playVideo(myUrl, startTime, endTime) { 
  var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  video.src = 'video/'+ myUrl;
  video.currentTime=startTime;
  video.play();

  var maxTime = endTime;
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(video.currentTime >= maxTime){
     // I NEED TO ADD CODE HERE!    
     playVideo(myUrl, startTime, endTime);
    }
  }, false);
} 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="myVideo" width="1000" height="800" controls autoplay loop>

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<br>
<a href="#" onclick="playVideo(firstUrl,firstStartTime, firstEndTime)" > Play </a>

</body>
</html>
```

.....
I want to build an video app (using Javascript) that repeats each segment of a video **3 times** before moving to the next segment.

There are **many videos** and each video has **many segments**.

The urllinks and segments are provided or pulled from database. They are constructed in a nested array like this:

```
 var sentences= 
    [
     ['journey27.mp4', 
      [
        [1, 2],
        [5, 7]
      ]
     ],
     ['journey28.mp4', 
      [
        [10, 12],
        [13, 17],
        [25, 36]
      ]
     ],
     ['journey29.mp4', 
      [
        [13, 15],
        [15, 19],
        [21, 30]
      ]
     ]
    ];
```

When I click "**play**" **once**, the app should **do all the following things**:

The app should play the video "**journey27.mp4**", from second 1 to 2, 3 times. That means it should play from second 1 to 2 then when the second is > than 2, it gets back and start from second 1 again and then the second is > than 2, it gets back and start from second 1 again and then second is > than 2, **it jump to the next** segment of video "**journey27.mp4**". That means it will do this

it plays "**journey27.mp4**" from 5 to 7, then
it plays "**journey27.mp4**" from 5 to 7, then
it plays "**journey27.mp4**" from 5 to 7, then it jumps to the next video

it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 10 to 12, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 10 to 12, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 10 to 12, then it jumps to the next segment of the video "**journey28.mp4**" and

it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 13 to 17, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 13 to 17, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 13 to 17, then it jumps to the next segment of the video "**journey28.mp4**" and

it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 25 to 36, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 25 to 36, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 25 to 36, then it jumps to the next video

it plays "**journey29.mp4**" from 13 to 15, then
it plays "**journey29.mp4**" from 13 to 15, then
it plays "**journey29.mp4**" from 13 to 15, then it jumps to the next segment of "**journey29.mp4**"

and so on.

**You don't have to worry** about the **playVideo** code because it works just fine.

But we need to put some loop or something like that inside the **addEventListener** to finish the requirement.

```
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
        if(video.currentTime >= maxTime){
         // I NEED TO ADD CODE HERE!    
         playVideo(myUrl, startTime, endTime);
        }
      }, false);
```

Can we create a loop inside the **video.addEventListener** to complete this task (javascript)?

Comment: Keep in mind you are adding the timeupdate event inside a function that is called in the event itself, this will add infinite events over time causing issues. Call the addEventListener outside the function and that will prevent it, the event will be triggered every frame as expected

Comment: @DiegoN., if I put the addEventListener outside the "playVideo", then it doesn't loop. You can try to run the code if you want

Comment: Just add a console.log inside the event listener function, it will be triggered each iteration one time more, causing memory leak. You can check that using the most basic scenario, just a video with the event binded. This event "timeupdate" binding one time will be your required loop, and in this event is where you should check interval, current iteration of the interval, and progress through your defined sections. I can't do a snippet now, if I get some free later time i'll do a better response ;)